# Simple configurable product conflict with ajax add to cart (Magento)

Tags: magento

I have a problem with my site being once you click on add to cart and select a custom option this sets the price to 0.00 it will add the product with the options but uses the lowest priced product instead of the one selected i have browsed for the last few days and think I’ve narrowed it down to another plugin AJAX Excellence i think conflicting with SCP i got my info from this link but have no idea what I’m looking for.
This problem doesnt happen if you go through the product description page only on the product listing pages which brings up a pop up of options to add to cart 
Your help will be appreciated.
Magento ver. 1.7.0.2